# javascript jquery like construction

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I wonder if it is possible to create some sort of construction where one could do the following:

`$("some element").somemethod(arg)`, which would be exactly the same as saying `$.somemethod("some element", arg)`

I know it is possible to use, for example, `$(selector).each(callback)` in jquery, which appears to be the equivalent of `$.each(selector, callback)`. I find it hard to understand how jquery does this, though. It seems like the method "each" is defined twice, but this is something I would like to avoid. Is this possible?

Comment: They actually are not equivalent? `$.fn.each = function(a,b){return $.each(this,a,b)};`

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: It is defined twice, however, the `$(selector).somemethod()` version uses the `$.someMethod()` version internally to keep the code DRY.

Comment: You can reference the api docs to get an understanding of the difference between these two functions and their respective usage: [`$(selector).each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`$.each(selector, callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)...

Answer (score 5):

They are defined twice, however the code that actually does the work is only written once.

```
$.myPlugin = function(element,text){
    $(element).text(text); // work is done here
    return element;
}
$.fn.myPlugin(function(text) {
    return $.myPlugin(this,text);
});
```

Here's an example of this being used inside jQuery's core:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L250

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible, you have to implement your own plugin for that.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.somemethod = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            // do something to each element here
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

---

```
function $(context){
    this.context = context;
    if(!(this instanceof $)) return new $(context);
}

$.prototype.somemethod = function(arg){
    // The bulk of the function is defined here, only once
    console.log("Doing some stuff to " + this.context + " with " + arg);
}

$.somemethod = function(context, arg){
    $(context).somemethod(arg);
}

$('body').somemethod(7); // Doing some stuff to body with 7
$.somemethod('body', 7); // Doing some stuff to body with 7
```